# Why does standard input() cause an EOF error

Tags: python, eoferror

I was solving a problem on HackerRank when I encountered the following problem in my code. I tested it out on my  Python (2.7.10) IDLE , and it was working fine. But it showed the following error on HackerRank:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 13, in <module>
    input_2=input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I entered the following code:

```
import sys 
input_2=""
n=int(input())
m=0
l=0
array=[]
main_array=[]
for i in range (0,n):
    inp=input()
    array=(inp.split(" "))
    main_array+=array   
for no in range(0,100000,1):    
    input_2=input()
    for m in range(0,len(main_array),2):
        l=0
        if input_2==main_array[m]:
            l+=1
            print (main_array[m]+"="+main_array[m+1])
    if l==0:
        print ("Not found")
```

I don't know why this error turned up in the HackerRank Engine.
Thanks

Comment: On online platforms there's usually a text box in which you place input, it isn't done as it is in your terminal.

Comment: It means you tried reading more lines of input than were provided. Give us a description of the input, or just a link to the problem.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: Which version of python are you using?  You tested using 2.7, but you should use `raw_input()` on 2.7.

Comment: i tried using raw_input on hackerrank but it didn't work

Comment: @YajurTayal read this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23079733/6107715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you exactly trying to achieve through your code, but you are getting an error due to the line `inp=input()`, which tries to take a string as input, whereas it's designed to take an `int`, `float`, or `string entered with quotes` in `python 2.7`. Use `raw_input()` instead to take the complete line as string input, and then split it with `space` as delimiter.

I followed the link you provided, and I see that the given question needs to be solved using `dictionaries`. Hence, instead of appending the `name` and `number`, just store it in `dictionary` as a `key-value` pair and for each query, just check whether the key exists in the dictionary or not. If not, print `Not found`, else print the key and its corresponding value. Here is the code for reference :

```
import sys
input_2=""
n = input()
m=0
l=0
array=[]
main_array={}
for i in range (0,n):
    inp=raw_input()
    array=(inp.split())
    main_array[array[0]] = array[1]
for i in range(0,n):
    take = raw_input()
    if take in main_array :
        print take+"="+main_array[take]
    else :
        print "Not found"
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 3):

I encountered similar EOF issues when I coded in HackerRank. Actually, there are 2 issues:

1. use `input()` in Python3 and `raw_input()` in Python2.
2. If you know the exact number of input, you can N-number for-loop to handle each `input()`. However, the difficulty is that you don't know how many inputs you will have. In this case, you will have to use `sys.stdin.readlines()` to convert them into a list, and then use a for-each loop.

The following codes are from "Editorial" of https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/

```
import sys 

# Read input and assemble Phone Book
n = int(input())
phoneBook = {}
for i in range(n):
    contact = input().split(' ')
    phoneBook[contact[0]] = contact[1]

# Process Queries
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()  # convert lines to list
for i in lines:
    name = i.strip()
    if name in phoneBook:
        print(name + '=' + str( phoneBook[name] ))
    else:
        print('Not found')
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this - this is the best answer. (They're still using this problem at HackerRank)