# Python 2.7 While Loop Don't Work

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
question = raw_input("Python or Ruby?")
while question != "Python":
    print "Nope!"
```

This is a simple one. I am an amateur and I am learning the basics. I tried something with this loop but it gives this error:

```
$python main.py
Python or Ruby?Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in 
    question = raw_input("Python or Ruby?")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Also when I try to see output in PyCharm nothing happens, just a blank output window occur.

Comment: That's a nice infinite loop you have there, but I don't see how this would raise that error.

Comment: The value of `question` does not change **inside** the while loop, so  the condition is never met - the loop is infinite.

Comment: How are you running this code? There seem to be several reasons for getting EOF on `input` e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079388/python-eof-error-raw-input) but it seems to depend on where you run it

Comment: While it has another obvious issue (cf other comments), your code snippet doesn't raise any `EOFError`.

Comment: This question is far too broad, please review this and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'While' loops are mainly used for detecting when something stays the same and/or changes. With your code, at the beginning it takes in user input and stores it as a variable. The while loop then infinitely checks it and if it does not equal "Python" it prints "Nope!", meaning that it will infinitely print "Nope!" over and over again. An 'if' statement would work much better:

```
if question != "Python":
    print "Nope!"
```

The 'if' statement will only check it once, instead of checking it infinitely. Hope this answer helped you!

Answer (score 2):

Looking for something like this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 
import sys
question = None
while question != "Python":
    question = raw_input("Python or Ruby? ->")

    if(question != "Python"):
        print("Nope!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an if-statement, rather than an infinite while-loop (see below).

```
question = raw_input('Python or Rub?')
while 'Python' not in question:
   print 'Nope!'
```

You can improve the statement comparing the answer in lower letters. Otherwise capital letters will produce a `Nope!` output, even if the answer is technically correct (when `Python` or `python` is both correct).

```
question = raw_input('Python or Rub?')
if 'python' not in question.lower():
   print 'Nope!'
```

Comment: That is, if `'Python' is not in question`, you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the while statment don't finish. Declare a definition can help you.

```
def Question():
 question = raw_input("Python or Ruby?")
 while question != "Python":
    print "Nope!"
    return Question()
 print "Correct"
 return 1
```

Or for best performance use the if statment recursivly:

```
def Question():
 question = raw_input("Python or Ruby?")
 if question == "Python":
    print "Correct"
    return 1
 print "nope"
 return Question()
```

`